# how to create a src in javascript including external variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

assume a `for` loop .how we can add `i` in src?
extracting src from local storage

```
for(let i;i<10;i++){
//create an img tag object with IMG name
IMG.src='/project/images/${i}/test.png'
}
```

Comment: Use backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: Use backticks like this: `IMG.src=\`/project/images/${i}/test.png\``

Comment: @Spectric tnx easy

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. backticks:

```
IMG.src = `example.com/images/${i}`
```

2. the `+`:

`IMG.src = 'example.com/images/'+i`

Both work, but I prefer the first option.